# Django FormSetView with custom validation

Tags: python, django, formset

I'm using the `ModelFormSetView` class in `django-extra-views` to create a formset view of all `WorkerStatus` entries connected to a `Worker`. I'd also like to use custom validation on the formset, so I've defined my own `formset_class` and `form_class` in the view. Here's the view definition:

```
class WorkerStatusUpdateView(ModelFormSetView):

    model = WorkerStatusEntry
    formset_class = WorkerStatusFormSet
    form_class = WorkerStatusForm

    template_name = 'staff/workers/worker_status_update.tmpl'

    can_delete = True
    can_order = False
    fields = ['status', 'start_date']

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.worker = Worker.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['worker_pk'])
        return super(WorkerStatusUpdateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(WorkerStatusUpdateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        ctx['worker'] = self.worker

        return ctx

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.worker.statuses.all()
```

...and here are the definitions of the form and formset respectively:

```
class WorkerStatusForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = WorkerStatusEntry
        fields = ['status', 'start_date']


class WorkerStatusFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):

    class Meta:
        model = WorkerStatusEntry

    def __init__(self, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WorkerStatusFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        print "Cleaning"
```

This results in a page where EVERY `WorkerStatusEntry` in the database is shown in the formset, regardless of `get_queryset()`. One thing you'll notice is that `WorkerStatusFormSet.__init__` takes a `queryset` argument: I put that there because there was a `queryset` argument passed to it from the `ModelFormSetView`, but I don't know what to do with it.

Another thing to note: if I take `formset_class = WorkerStatusFormSet` out of the view definition, the correct queryset shows up in the formset. However I need to use my own formset class to validate across the whole formset. Unless there's another way?

Comment: It's not a good idea to change the signature of the `__init__` method like you have done. If you look at the [`BaseModelFormSet`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L556) code, you can see it already takes a queryset, so I don't think you need to override `__init__` at all. Try removing it, and if you still have problems, update your question with the new code.

Comment: Ah... that was the issue. I guess this is a wake-up call not to blindly overload the `__init__` function before I need to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `WorkerStatusFormSet.__init__` method. Looking at the code for [`BaseModelFormSet`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L556), the `__init__` method already takes a queryset parameter. Since you aren't doing anything in your `__init__` method except calling `super()`, the easiest fix is to remove it.

It's not a good idea to change the signature of the `__init__` method as you have done for two reasons

```
def __init__(self, queryset, *args, **kwargs):
    super(WorkerStatusFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

1. You have changed the order of the arguments. If you look at the code for `BaseModelFormset`, the first argument is data. That means that data might be incorrectly assigned to queryset if somebody calls WorkerStatusFormSet(data, ...)
2. You do not do anything with `queryset` or pass it to `super()`, so it is lost.